# How to show a Dialog on a non activity class?

Tags: android, android-dialog

I am very new to android studio and I wanna create this custom Dialog from a non activity class, but I am having trouble with is context. My code is shown below.

P.S: Sorry for the bad formatting in coding

```
package com.example.geotagv3;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    Dialog hx1;
    private static Context context;

    public HomeFragment(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_frag,container,false);



        hx1 = new Dialog(context);


    }



    private void showHx1(View v){

       hx1.setContentView(R.layout.hx1_layout);
       hx1.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: `private static Context context;` don't do that, and `public HomeFragment(Context context){` don't do that, it will break

Comment: Try with getActivity() not using the context. But first, you must to change the first line in onCreate. You are returing the inflate result, so the dialog creation will not be executed ever.